# Invalid field ContactPhone on SObject Case

Tags: apex, visualforce, case, standard-objects

I have a Visualforce page which has a Case form. It's pretty standard. However when I try to refer the ContactPhone in the inputField, the editor throws an error saying

> Invalid field ContactPhone on SObject Case

Here is the code:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:form>
  ....
  <apex:inputField value="{!mycase.ContactPhone}"/>
  ....
</apex:form>
```

Controller class:

```
public Case mycase {get; set;}

public MyController() {
  mycase = new Case();
}
```

I am not using a standard controller but a custom one. As soon as I try to save my page with that inputField, it throws the above error. I have to comment it in order to save the page. It doesn't do that for any other field.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Update: A ContactPhone field does exist on the Cse object for the org I am working on.

[image]

Comment: Check in the fields list is there any field with this name `ContactPhone`?

Comment: There is no such field called contactPhone on case object. check the available fields https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm

Comment: Yes, there is one on the Case Object I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasePhone is read-only so it will not be allowed in an inputfield.

The value in the field is fetched from the associated Contact object. If you need to edit it, you have to edit it on the Contact. Any update to the Contact's phone number will be reflected on the Case object as well.

See docs: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_fields.htm

> Phone number of a case’s contact. The number is added when you add a
>   contact to a case. This field is read only.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have checked the fields first.

Comment: No problem. I think it would help if the errormessage was a bit more self-explanatory :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard field ContactPhone on Case.
Seems you want to access Contact's phone. Try this :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!mycase.Contact.Phone}"/>
```

Comment: Just updated my question with the picture of the fields.